# How to declare current date in application.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

[image]

I have one variable in `application.properties` file 'footer_note' and now I want to store current date value in this variable but unable to do this.
I can do this in my Java code but requirement is to store that current date value in `application.properties` file and fetch from there and display it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597748/add-timestamp-variable-to-folder-path-value-in-application-properties

Answer (score 1):

You can set before springRun in main method.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("footer.note",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()....
    }
```